# Переменная в регулярных выражениях

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
$filter = "& !preg_match(\"/title='Маг'/\", $str)";
$f = file_get_contents("$page");
    preg_match_all("/<BR><BR><\/td><\/tr><\/table>(<table class=wb.+<\/td><\/tr><\/table>)<\/td><\/tr><\/table>/s", $f, $r);
    preg_match_all("/<tr>.*?<\/tr>/", $r[1][0], $r);
    echo "<table class=\"table1\">\r\n";

    $off = 1;
    foreach($r[0] as $str)
    {
        if(!preg_match('/alt="В игре"/', $str) & !preg_match('/alt="В бою"/', $str) & !preg_match('/alt="В таверне"/', $str) .$filter)
        {
            $str = preg_replace("/<tr><td class=wblight width=30>([^<]+)</", "<tr><td class=wblight width=30>$off.<", $str);
            $str = preg_replace("/<a href='(pl_info.php\?id=[\d]+)'/", "<a target=\"_blank\" href='http://www.heroeswm.ru/$1'", $str);

            echo $str, "\r\n";
    $off++;
        }
    }
    echo 
    "</table>";
```

Почему $filter который вставлен в код и который должен отсеять строки со значением не работает? Если на прямую вставить то отсеивает, а если через переменную, то нет.

Comment: Все работает! Спасибо!

Comment: А если я хочу ещё несколько фильтров добавить, то что мне делать?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы ересь делаете О_О

В php нет "директив компилятора", нельзя использовать константы и переменные как части логических выражений.

Даже если вы там что-то намутите, `"& !preg_match(\"/title='Маг'/\", $str)"` будет просто возвращать TRUE как "непустая строка".

Максимум можно сделать так:

```
function myFilter($str) { return !preg_match("/title='Маг'/", $str); }
$filter = "myFilter";

/* code */
if(!preg_match('/alt="В игре"/', $str) && !preg_match('/alt="В бою"/', $str) && !preg_match('/alt="В таверне"/', $str) && $filter($str))
/* code */
```

Comment: 
    function myFilter($str) { return !preg_match("/title='Маг'/", $str); }
    $filter = "myFunction";//Внимательней копипастим ;)
    $filter = "myFilter";
    




Comment: Да, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй так:

```
function myFilter($str) {
$filter = array("title='Маг'",
        'alt="В игре"',
        'alt="В бою"'
        );//через запятую значения которые обязательно должны присутствовать.
foreach($filter as $r){
    if(!strpos($str,$r))return false;
}
     return true;
}

/*code*/
if(myFilter($str))
/*code*/
```